# Adding custom attribute search in existing wordpress sidebar search in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

## Introduction

Hi all, I hope all devs are fine. For better understanding I am creating 3 sections.

I am new to wordpress development and Just have learned a little bit about plugin development and how they work.

### User Requirements

Client Wants to add search products by users/vendors in an existing search form which is inside sidebar.php. it is ajax based search.

In our case user/vendors would be either **individual or Pro**.

#### how will it work

So when customer selects individual along with other existing attributes (size, color) it should show me products of all the individual users. If nothing is selected it should show all products from both users

### What I have done so far

I copied the file (Sidebar) in my child theme and manipulated it to add two check boxes.

I saw the theme's database. BUT i don't know how to make check boxes work to get desired output.

PS

I am stuck on this problem for five days. Brain's not working anymore

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include the code in your post to show what you have tried!